what does this grammar mean? "wire test_net = mubi4_test_true_strict(scanmode_i)"
Any one knows what does this definition mean?
"wire test_net = mubi4_test_true_strict(scanmode_i)"
i don't understand the meaning of such usage.
usually the wire is defined just like blow in verilog/sveriog
wire test_net;

It’s the equivalent of this continuous assignment
wire test_net;
assign test_net = mubi4_test_true_strict(scanmode_i);

Note that it will call the function when there is a change on scanmode_i regardless of what other signals the function might reference.
